# Stopping multiple models and views from updating each other

Tags: javascript, jquery, model-view-controller, backbone.js

I have been having an issue with a view updating another view. I have two different views with separate HTML structures that seem to be interacting with one another. I am guessing that either a view or model is staying hidden, event though most interactions are listenTo events. Any thoughts?

I have a two views, createContact and editContact that both live within the model, Contact. The issue comes about when you add a new contact and then edit any other contact. If the contact was created from a previous session, there are no update issues, it is only after the createContact view saves a new contact. After creating, every additional update request via the editContact adds a new network request. For example, if I add a contact and then edit another contact, I see two network requests, one for the current contact id, and a second for the updated contact. If I then go into another contact to edit, it will add a 3rd network request and then try to overwrite the other contact id's from previous add/updates.

I initially realized that I was appending new views over and over which caused redundancy issues. I removed the .append() situations and even have removed the model upon save. I am not sure why this is holding on to previous views/ models.

I added a new contact (lets call them contact 3) with an id of 869452a845b472c4621778ef61047b53, and then I edited contact 2 with an id of 869452a845b472c4621778ef61047425. Everything seems to be working just fine with a single post request and a single put request that both work correctly. Upon editing the final contact, contact 1 with an id of 869452a845b472c4621778ef61047af5, I start to get duplicate requests. For easier reference:

Contact 3 - POST - ID: 869452a845b472c4621778ef61047b53
Contact 2 - PUT - ID: 869452a845b472c4621778ef61047425
Contact 1 - PUT - ID: 869452a845b472c4621778ef61047af5

This is inside of my save function for the createContact view. The same concept is done within the editContact view, just with slightly different class names (for additional precaution):

```
    this.model.set({
        names:[{
            familyName: this.$('.name-family').val(),
            givenName: this.$('.name-given').val(),
            honorificPrefix:"",
            honorificSuffix: this.$('.name-suffix').val(),
            middleName:""
        }],
        favorite: this.$( '.isFavorited' ).hasClass('zmdi-star'),
        share: this.$( '.isShared' ).hasClass('zmdi-check-square'),
        organizations: orgArray,
        phoneNumbers: phoneArray,
        addresses: addressArray,
        urls: [],
        imClients: [],
        emailAddresses: emailArray,
        events: [],
        notes: this.$("textarea[name='notes']").val() !== '' ? [this.$("textarea[name='notes']").val()] : []
    });

    App.Contacts2.add(this.model);

    this.model.save(null ,{
        method: 'POST',
        success: function () {
            App.Emitter.trigger('snackbar', 'Contact Saved!', 3000);
            App.Master.changeView('contacts');
            App.Contacts2.remove(this.model);

        },
        error: function () {
            console.info('contact save error');
            App.Contacts2.remove(this.model);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like you'll probably have the wrong `this` in your callbacks (usually defaults to `window`) as you didn't bind any. Therefore `this.model` ( = `window.model`) will probably be `undefined`. That's why you're not really removing anything.

My suggestion:

**using underscore's `bind()`:**

```
this.model.save(null ,{
    method: 'POST',
    success: _.bind(function () {
        App.Emitter.trigger('snackbar', 'Contact Saved!', 3000);
        App.Master.changeView('contacts');
        App.Contacts2.remove(this.model);

    }, this),
    error: _.bind(function () {
        console.info('contact save error');
        App.Contacts2.remove(this.model);
    }, this),
});
```

or

```
this.model.save(null ,{
    method: 'POST',
    success: function () {
        App.Emitter.trigger('snackbar', 'Contact Saved!', 3000);
        App.Master.changeView('contacts');
    },
    error: function () {
        console.info('contact save error');
    },
    complete: _.bind(function () {
        App.Contacts2.remove(this.model);
    }, this),
});
```

**using helper variable `self`:**

```
var self = this;
this.model.save(null ,{
    method: 'POST',
    success: function () {
        App.Emitter.trigger('snackbar', 'Contact Saved!', 3000);
        App.Master.changeView('contacts');
        App.Contacts2.remove(this.model);

    },
    error: function () {
        console.info('contact save error');
        App.Contacts2.remove(this.model);
    }
});
```

**Notes**

- I don't know your code too well, so I don't know if it matters whether or not the model gets removed before or after the changeView.
- Also maybe you're forgetting somewhere to remove event-hooks/listeners with `this.model.off()` and `this.model.stopListening()`?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks so much for the help. In the end, the issue was in fact (though I didn't post the code that supports this) just a bunch of views being added to the model without being removed. A simple .remove() when leaving the view was all that was needed to make everything work. Thank you!